# Does the sum of reciprocals of square free numbers converge to an elementary function plus a constant?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_i$ be the $i$th square free number and let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Since $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ converges to $\ln(n)+ \gamma$ and the density of square free numbers among positive integers is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, does it follow that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{a_i}$ converges to $\frac{6}{\pi^2}\ln(n)+k$ for some constant $k$?

Comment: It isn't correct to even say that $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$ converges to anything. What is correct is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(n) - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1 i = \gamma$$

It seems minor, but it is a very important distinction.